# Adding image to particle emitter and stopping after a duration in swift/ios

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to learn and understand the emitter functions of CAEmitter, but I'm currently a little bit stuck. I want to add an image for the emitter and make it stop after a duration.

I've got a view that I'm using to emit some particles, and I want them to only appear emit when the view appears for around 10 seconds, then stop. I also am unsure how to attach a UI image with a png, instead of using CGrect.

Thanks for any help and advice!

```
import UIKit

class ParticleView: UIView {

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(15,8), false, 1)
    let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextAddRect(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 8))
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(con)
    let im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // make a cell with that image
    var cell = CAEmitterCell()
    cell.birthRate = 10
    cell.color = UIColor(red:0.5, green:0.5, blue:0.5, alpha:1.0).CGColor
    cell.redRange = 1
    cell.blueRange = 1
    cell.greenRange = 1
    cell.lifetime = 5
    cell.alphaSpeed = -1/cell.lifetime
    cell.velocity = -100
    cell.spinRange = 10.0
    cell.scale = 1.0;
    cell.scaleRange = 0.2;
    cell.emissionRange = CGFloat(M_PI)/5.0
    cell.contents = im.CGImage

    var emit = CAEmitterLayer()
    emit.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 0)
    emit.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(30,100)
    emit.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
    emit.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerLine

    emit.emitterCells = [cell]
    self.layer.addSublayer(emit)

}
```

}

Comment: Kind of broad. You're asking a lot of things at once! More focused questions are easier to deal with.

Comment: "I also am unsure how to attach a UI image with a png, instead of using CGrect." Sorry, but your code _does_ start with a UIImage and then attach it. So what is it that you are unsure of?

Comment: May I ask (while I'm up) why on earth this code is in `drawRect:`???? An emitter has nothing whatever to do with the drawing of a view.

Comment: I don't know how else to make it visible. How should I be attaching the emitter?

Comment: I don't say there's anything wrong with how you're attaching it. It's just that you're triggering it in `drawRect:`. You have no idea why or when that will be called, and every time it is, you'll be doing this again. That's nuts.

Comment: "for around 10 seconds, then stop" Okay, again, what is it that you don't know? Do you not know how to make an emitter stop? Or is that you don't know how to do something after 10 seconds?

Comment: How to make the emitter stop emitting after 10 seconds (I assume I'd use NSTimer to do so) - Sorry if this is vague, I'm still finding my feet with all this ios business!

Comment: OK, excellent! So, to make it stop, just do the opposite of what you're doing - remove it. You started it by adding it, stop it by removing it.

Comment: I'm uncertain of how I should be adding correctly to my viewControllers. Do I add an empty view, make it a class of 'ParticleView' and call .hidden = true/false to make it appear/disappear?

Comment: You don't add to a view controller. You add to a view. It's fine to add it the way you're adding it. Just don't do it in `drawRect:`, which is called unpredictably and possibly many times, and is intended for one purpose - you draw the content of this view. The emitter is not its content, it's just a subview. So just have a function that does what you're doing, and when it's time to show the emitter, call that function.

Comment: Ok thanks! You've helped cleared up some of my questions. Would you like me to delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice workaround to stop CAEmitter:

1. Create 2 identical view controllers with the same layout
2. Implement a Start and Stop button on both (to begin and end the CAEmitter)
3. Connect the Stop button of each view controller to each other with a “Show Detail (e.g. Replace) Segue and deselect "Animates"

When you hit “Stop” button it will make a seamless transition to the identical VC without emitter particles!!  But what is really happening is that you are just switching to a replica view controller.  This is not an elegant solution but it is the only reliable way that I have found to stop a CAEmitter (segue to a different VC) all of the other solutions are "buggy"

[visual of how the VCs are set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE4gX.png)

Comment: Store a local instance of the emitter, and then remove it from the sublayer using a method. That should do the trick, without having to duplicate view controllers.